# CGAL boolean operation on 3d mesh with color

Tags: c++, boolean, geometry, mesh, cgal

what I'm trying to do is performing CGAL boolean operator (union operator) on 2 models that has RGB color for each vertex. but the result doesn't retain the color info.
Maybe you have an idea how to solve this issue.

Here are the models for doing boolean operation (coff format):

[model1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DagmyDHB9ljfM9UJXPZjQHr6niFB3tJq)

[model2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n0NqNiWUQpURrpwT1MYo0w73mQcqwLfB)

[image of input models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AS6k.png)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_items_with_id_3.h>

#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement.h>

#include <fstream>


typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3> Mesh;

namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* filename1 = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "data/b1.off";
    const char* filename2 = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : "data/b2.off";
    std::ifstream input(filename1);

    Mesh mesh1, mesh2;
    if (!input || !(input >> mesh1))
    {
        std::cerr << "First mesh is not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    input.close();
    input.open(filename2);
    if (!input || !(input >> mesh2))
    {
        std::cerr << "Second mesh is not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Mesh out;
    bool valid_union = PMP::corefine_and_compute_union(mesh1, mesh2, out);

    if (valid_union)
    {
        std::cout << "Union was successfully computed\n";
        std::ofstream output("union.off");
        output << out;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Union could not be computed\n";
    return 1;
}
```

What I get at the end has correct mesh but doesn't retain the color info.
Is there any chance to fix the color info?

[union model as result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EJSE4T4tqV2KCx9o3-rr57j1wLSCN_Ey)

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet possible. There is one hidden parameter in `corefine` to preserve those attributes but the output builder for the Boolean operation is missing a visitor (that I hope to have time to add in CGAL 4.13).

There a few workaround but none of them will handle all the possible cases.

**EDIT**:
In CGAL 4.13 this will be possible by passing in the named parameter a visitor. This [PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3111) is the one adding the support and is already merged into the master branch. The following [example](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/examples/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement_mesh_union_with_attributes.cpp) shows how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your info. If I know a workaround I would like to try it, even if the result is not perfect. for me the color of the first model is important. What I was thinking to implement is to search each point of first model into the result model and assign a color value to that. but this has order of O(mxn) which is very slow for 1M points.

Comment: you can get all the color information of one mesh of all non modified faces by doing an inplace operation. In practice, it means for example to copy `mesh1` in `out` and call the function on  `corefine_and_compute_union(out, mesh2, out);`.

Comment: thank you sloriot for the hint. I have tried but still didn't work. maybe I should define another data type for Mesh. the actual one is:                          
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3> Mesh;

Comment: I found that  there is a command in cgal library to load "coff" format which contains color RGB. But I don't know how to use it. My first attempt is how to define data types.

Comment: I edited my answer since the change has been added in the 4.13 development branch.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that there is a command in cgal library to load "coff" format
>   which contains color RGB. But I don't know how to use it. My first
>   attempt is how to define data types.

As far as I know, only the Surface_mesh data structure is able to work with a COFF file. You can look at the code of the Surface_mesh_io_plugin in Polyhedron/demo/Polyhedron.
The COFF format is a standard that is quite well documented.